# UnknownFormat Error When Doing an AJAX Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I wish to have a little search box, which will allow the user to search other users by name, with the results showing in the box in a sort of list.  Much like how, on a site like amazon, you can type a search into the bar and it will have a dropdown, except on mine I am not doing "autocomplete" (at least not yet)

At the moment, however, when I try to search, it says "ActionController::UnknownFormat in ChatRoomsController#search_users", with an explanation:

```
ChatRoomsController#search_users is missing a template for this request
format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: [] 
NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests, this action would normally respond 
with 204 No Content: an empty white screen. Since you're loading it in a 
web browser, we assume that you expected to actually render a template, 
not nothing, so we're showing an error to be extra-clear. If you expect 
204 No Content, carry on. That's what you'll get from an XHR or API 
request. Give it a shot.
```

So it seems to be saying that this *isn't* an AJAX request, but I have have pretty much copied my code from the RailsCast on AJAX searching (just removed some pagination bits), so this confuses me.

Here are the relevant parts of my code:

```
# chat_rooms/show.html.erb
<%= form_tag search_path, :id => "search", :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search for User", :name => nil, class: "button-butt" %>
<% end %>

<% for result in @users_results %>
  <%= result.name %>
<% end %>
```

and the controller:

```
# chat_rooms_controller.rb
def search_users
  @users_results = User.search(params[:search])
end
```

the model's search method:

```
# user.rb
def self.search(term)
  where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%")
end
```

I think my routing is OK, but just in case it isn't:

```
# routes.rb
get '/search_users', to: 'chat_rooms#search_users', as: 'search'
```

and finally, the javascript:

```
#application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$("#search input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#search").attr("action"), $("#search").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you include the exact error from the server log in the question?

Comment: @Pavan done.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `search_users.html.erb`?

Comment: no, do I need to make a view for that?

Comment: you see, I want to be able to stay on the same page when doing the search; so I don't want to sort of redirect to a different page when submitting the search.  I just want to send the search request, and have the results pop into the list below the searchbar if you see what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# routes.rb
get '/search_users', to: 'chat_rooms#search_users', as: 'search'
```

Since your `routes.rb` specifies that you will have a `search_users` action in `ChatRoomsController` and it(action) seems to be present.

When request arrived from the form, it landed on that action but, since the template named `search_users.html.erb` is missing, its displaying this error.

---

### Solution

Either handle the request and respond with a template mentioned in the error message; or, rename and redesign the routes and controller.

### Edit: 1

> I just want to send the search request, and have the results pop into the list below the searchbar if you see what I mean.

If so, do following:

```
# chat_rooms_controller.rb
def search_users
  @users_results = User.search(params[:search])
  render :show
end
```

Plz comment, if its not helping.

Comment: thank you.  i fixed it by defining a JS response and using `respond_to`.